# PostgreSQL - How to get the count of elements in a column list

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, aggregate-functions

This is how my orders table looks like :

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
| id  | order
-----------------------------------------------------------
|1    |[{"order_quantity" : 2, "active" : TRUE, "price" : $100 }, {"order_quantity" : 4, "active" : FALSE, "price" : $200 }]
|2    |[{"order_quantity" : 2, "active" : TRUE, "price" : $170 }]
|3    |[{"order_quantity" : 2, "active" : TRUE, "price" : $120 }]
|4    |[{"order_quantity" : 2, "active" : TRUE, "price" : $150 }, {"order_quantity" : 3, "active" : TRUE, "price" : $200 }, {"order_quantity" : 5, "active" : TRUE, "price" : $200 }]
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

the results wanted when doing the count for the `JSON` elements inside the brackets `WHERE active == TRUE` in each element :

```
------------
id  | counts
------------
|1  |   1
|2  |   1
|3  |   1
|4  |   3
------------
```

This is what I'm using but it doesn't give the data i'm looking for because it doesn't not look into each dictionary to see if  `active == TRUE`

```
SELECT id, json_array_length(order::JSON)
FROM orders

------------
id  | counts
------------
|1  |   2
|2  |   1
|3  |   1
|4  |   3
------------
```

Comment: `select id, array_length(string_to_array(orders::text, 'TRUE'), 1) - 1 as counts from ...`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `json_array_elements()` which selects all elements of the json array, filter the elements and finally count remaining elements grouping by `id`.

```
select id, count(id)
from orders
cross join json_array_elements(orders) elem
where (elem->>'active')::boolean
group by 1
order by 1;
```

Live demo in [Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=7e08908eae417d179d4289251028c06d)

Notes:

- use set returning functions (like `json_array_elements()`) in `FROM` clause as [lateral join](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.3#LATERAL_JOIN);
- json boolean values should look like `true` (not `TRUE`);
- there is no `money` type in json, use `300` instead of `$300`;
- use [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/) to verify json values.

Answer (score 2):

I started by normalizing the orders by each order using [json_array_elements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html) and then was able to do the count and check if the `active = TRUE`

```
WITH normalize_all_orders AS (
    SELECT id
       , json_array_elements(order::JSON) as order_line
    FROM orders
)

SELECT id
       , COUNT(order_line) AS orders_counts

WHERE order_line::json->>'soundFlag' = 'true'
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: +1 for the thinking about the data normalization. BTW the query can be more simple, like `select id, (select count(*) from json_array_elements(order::JSON) as t(j) where j->>'soundFlag' = 'true') as orders_counts from orders;` (grouping avoided).